# How to simplify this code? (inside print)

Tags: python, optimization, printing

I would like to simplify a part of this code:

```
while True:
    print("\nEcris 'quitter' pour quitter")
    try:
        a=float(input("Rentre a: "))
        b=float(input("Rentre b: "))
        c=float(input("Rentre c: "))
    except:
        print("Rentre des chiffres, pas des lettres!")
        continue
    delta=b**2-4*a*c
    print("delta =",delta)
    if delta>0:
        x1=(-b+sqrt(delta))/2*a
        x2=(-b-sqrt(delta))/2*a
        print("Les racines de la fonction"+ str("%+d" % a)+'x²',str("%+d" % b)+'x',str("%+d" % c),"sont x1 =",x1," et x2 =",x2)
    elif delta==0:
        print("La racine de ta fonction",str("%+d" % a)+'x²',str("%+d" % b)+'x',str("%+d" % c),"est x0 =", -b/2*a)
        print("On peut aussi dire que ta fonction est égale à",str(a)+'('+str(b/2*a)+'x)**2')
    elif delta<0:
        print("La fonction",str("%+d" % a)+'x²',str("%+d" % b)+'x',str("%+d" % c),"n'admet pas de racine")
```

I want to do this, (I tried but it didn't work)

```
fonction = str("%+d" % a)+'x²',str("%+d" % b)+'x',str("%+d" % c)
print("La racine de la fonction"+ fonction +"sont x1 =",x1," et x2 =",x2)
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks

sorry for the french

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Why would you call `str()` when the result is already a `str`?

Comment: actually it isn't an error, but it looks bad: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7bzKw)

Comment: `str(fmt % v)` is just `(fmt % v)`.  Of course, you could use `str(str(str(str(str(fmt % v)))))` if you want to pile up pointless calls to `str`...

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Python 3.6 and above, [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) makes it even more readable as the variable is referenced directly into the `format` braces:

```
print(f"Les racines de la fonction {a:+}x²{b:+}x{c:+} sont x1 = {x1} et x2 = {x2}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the first one:

```
print("Les racines de la fonction {:+}x²{:+}x{:+} sont x1 = {} et x2 = {}".format(a, b, c, x1, x2))
```

The others simplify similarly.

Comment: Using `f-string` would be even more readable :)

Comment: f-strings are too new. Plenty of people are still using even 3.3.

Comment: Showing how to use it would do no harm. Python 3.6 has been around for a year now (almost).